# How can I monitor HTTP traffic from BlueStacks?

Tags: fiddler, bluestacks

I want monitor HTTP traffic from BlueStacks so that I can debug web analytics tracking - any idea how?

For example, my application calles my server. I want to know what actual API my application actually called during testing.

I do not see any HTTP requests in Fidller even when using the BlueStacks.

I thought fiddler capture all internet request done by any software.

Comment: Jim? you have marked an answer which scores -3 as a correct answer

Comment: the whold combo smells like promo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2019, Fiddler has been updated to support Proxy, just set up your BlueStacks to use Fiddler's proxy and you can capture all HTTP/HTTPS traffic going out from it.

Comment: As long as the traffic goes through the proxy you can use whatever browser you like. The plugins (which are available for Chrome/Firefox also) are for capturing traffic to localhost.

Comment: why would you say something like that? you can use fiddler with Chrome/Firefox and any other application that has proxy setting.

Comment: I am saying that because he is talking about running it INSIDE BlueStacks, and not inside a "browser" (i.e. from within chrome) of bluestack, but rather inside an application

Comment: You just don't know how fiddler works. It's possible to capture traffic from Nox/Memu emulator if you configure the Wifi to Computer IP:8888 in emulator.

Answer (score 26):

Actually you can use fiddler. You see, fiddler configures the winINET proxy to go through it (the one used by internet explorer and all other microsoft software, but sometimes even third pary software uses winINET proxy config - that is why some programs just magically work with fiddle). Some programs ignore wininet config completly and have their own method of setting a proxy (like firefox, chrome). And other programs, like bluestacks, have no support for proxy at all.

But you can force BlueStacks to go through the fiddler proxy. A tool which can do that, and which has a tutorial on this, is ProxyCap:
http://www.proxycap.com/bluestacks.html
Just use 127.0.0.1 as server and 8888 as port number in configuration of the proxies in proxycap. You must also add HD-Agent and HD-Frontend executables in the rules, as specified in the last part of the step-by-step guide.

Unfortunately, proxycap is a 30 day trial. You can use free proxifiers out there. Find something that supports http.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers
I did manage to make this work with proxyCap myself and haven't tried anything else yet.

I think this is better for http traffic sniffing than wireshark which is for lower level network sniffing

Comment: I have done as you said @farkon but i am unable to track the https traffic fiddler gives remotecertificatenamemismatcherror I have installed fiddler certificate in bluestack but still its not working..

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I did everything as in the post yet I see no traffic at all from BlueStacks... any idea?

Comment: fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake failed. System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Answer (score 6):

Use [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/download.html) to let Fiddler capture the trafic.

ProxyCap forwards all Bluestack communication to HTTP proxy (in this case our proxy is Fiddler).

The full step-by-step guide, how to redirect the Bluestack application traffic through proxy, is [HERE](http://www.proxycap.com/bluestacks.html).

Use 127.0.0.1:8888 as proxy address. That is the address of Fiddler on the local computer.

Comment: I have done as you said @farkon but i am unable to track the https traffic fiddler gives remotecertificatenamemismatcherror I have installed fiddler certificate in bluestack but still its not working..

Comment: what is the purpose of this answer? it adds nothing new to my answer which was 2 months older. Even the links and the instructions are the same...

Comment: @frakon thanks, it helped me with http but how to configure it to https. Because fiddler doesn't decode https if I use your answer. Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: check if you port is 8888, in my case it is 8866 because another software is using 8888. Go to http://ipv4.fiddler:8888/ and confirm the Echo service is on. If not, go to Fiddler, config > connections > and get the port used by fiddler on FIDLER LISTENS ON PORT

Comment: HD-ConfigHttpProxy.exe set must be enough;

Comment: problems with latest 5 there no such option; and droid proxy not help

Comment: proxyCap or profixer or similar made net work, but fiddler not able to decrypt, maybe that stupid tools work like additional proxy chain with separated additional own certs :(

Answer (score 3):

Today I tried Fiddler - ProxyCap - BlueStacks.  It didn't work at first. After I added "HD-Plus-Service.exe" everything was Okay. It seems like new bluestacks versions don't use HD-Network.exe?  Anyway my program list includes:

- HD-Service.exe
- HD-Agent.exe
- HD-Frontend.exe
- HD-Network.exe
- HD-Plus-Service.exe
- HD-LogRotatorService.exe

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler has a documentation regarding how to capture traffic of Android devices: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid. You can use the same config for bluestack

Answer (score 0):

In addition, for latest Bluestacks3 version here are the list of apps you need to add to your both program lists:

- HD-Agent.exe ( from "C:\Program Files\Bluestacks\" )
- HD-Player.exe ( from "C:\Program Files\Bluestacks\" )
- Bluestacks.exe ( from where you installed Bluestacks )